# is udpclient.available the same as socket poll?

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I'm making a while true loop in order to send info and receive only when needed. I picked udpclient instead of socket for the ease of implementation. socket has a poll method that tells you if theres data to be received and I guessed udpclient.available will be similar. however in my main loop despite receiving information udpclient.available constantly only says 0.
the only possible conclusion I can think of is that sending and receiving (that I do beforehand as a bootstrapping process) changes the connection and udpclient.available will only return data that's available in the current socket (and not on the port). However this is most likely not the case because I connected the socket to ipaddress.any and it still doesnt work

code:`

```
class MainLine_DHT
    {
        private string id;
        private byte[] IdBytes;
        private string stringBytes;
        private BTree<Bucket> Routing_Table;
        private const char left = '1';
        private const char right = '0';
        private int port;
        private static RNGCryptoServiceProvider rnd = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        private Dictionary<IPEndPoint, Token> tokenHandler;
        private Dictionary<byte[], PeerList> peers;
        private UdpClient connection;
        public MainLine_DHT(int port)
        {
            this.peers = new Dictionary<byte[], PeerList>();
            this.tokenHandler = new Dictionary<IPEndPoint, Token>();
            this.IdBytes = new byte[20];
            rnd.GetBytes(IdBytes);//makes random byte array composed of 20 bytes
            this.id = BitConverter.ToString(IdBytes).Replace("-", string.Empty); //changes bytes to hex string simailair to sha 1
            this.id = this.id.ToLower();
            //changes from upper to lowercase
            this.stringBytes = BMethods.BytesToString(IdBytes);
            //bytes array repreasented as string
            this.Routing_Table = new BTree<Bucket>(new Bucket());
            Console.WriteLine("myid:" + stringBytes);
            this.port = port;
            this.connection = new UdpClient(this.port);
            this.connection.Client.SendTimeout = 5000;
            this.connection.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
        }
        public void start()
        {
            //starts the dht process
            bootstrap();
            //Start bootstrapping process
            MainLoop();
        }
           }
        private void MainLoop()
        {
            while (true)
            {
              if(this.connection.available >0)
               {
                IpEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,this.port);
                byte[] data = this.connection.receive(ref endpoint);
            }
    
        }


public void bootstrap()
        {
       
 /* this method contacts known bootstrapping nodes with a find_node query with my id as the target.
         * this method will continueslly send continuously send find_node query to closer and closer node with my own id as the target until no closer nodes can be found*/
        IPAddress[] ipAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses("router.bittorrent.com"); //gets ip of known bootstrapping node
        var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddresses[0], 6881); //make end point object with ip from earlier and known port

        var parser = new BencodeParser(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
        // Encode the query as a byte array
        byte[] tkey = new byte[2];
        rnd.GetBytes(tkey);
        //generates t key
        var queryBytes = KRPC.find_node_query(this.IdBytes, this.IdBytes, tkey);
        // Creates bencoded request dictionary as byte array

        this.FindNodeQuery(new IPEndPoint[] { endpoint }, this.IdBytes, tkey);

        while(true)
        {
            DHTNode[] ThreeClosestNodes = this.FindClosestBucket(this.id).Return_a_Closest(3);
            //Gets 3 closest nodes in routing table to my id
            IPEndPoint[] arr = new IPEndPoint[ThreeClosestNodes.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < ThreeClosestNodes.Length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = new IPEndPoint(ThreeClosestNodes[i].Address, ThreeClosestNodes[i].Port);
            }
            this.FindNodeQuery(arr, this.IdBytes, tkey);
            DHTNode[] test = this.FindClosestBucket(this.id).Return_a_Closest(3);
            int count = 0;
            for(int l=0;l<test.Length;l++)
            {
                if (DHTNode.Equals(test[l], ThreeClosestNodes[l]))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == 3)
                break;
        }
    }

    private void FindNodeQuery(IPEndPoint[] arr, byte[] target, byte[] tkey)
    {
        var parser = new BencodeParser(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
        // Encode the query as a byte array
        var queryBytes = KRPC.find_node_query(target, target, tkey);
        // Creates bencoded request dictionary as byte array

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            connection.SendAsync(queryBytes, queryBytes.Length, arr[i]);
        }
        IPEndPoint point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.port);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data = connection.Receive(ref point);
                //recieves data
                BDictionary response = parser.Parse<BDictionary>(data);
                BString nodes = ((BDictionary)response["r"])["nodes"] as BString;
                byte[] nodesBytes = nodes.Value.ToArray();
                for (int j = 0; j < nodesBytes.Length; j += 26)
                {
                    byte[] nodeId = new byte[20];
                    Array.Copy(nodesBytes, j, nodeId, 0, 20);
                    //first 20 bytes is id
                    byte[] ipBytes = new byte[4];
                    Array.Copy(nodesBytes, j + 20, ipBytes, 0, 4);
                    IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(ipBytes);
                    //21-24 byte is ip
                    int port = (nodesBytes[j + 24] << 8) | nodesBytes[j + 25];
                    //23-26 byte is port
                    this.AddNode(BMethods.BytesToId(nodeId), ip, port);
                    // add node
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                continue;
                //if timeout conditions are met continue
            }
        }

    }`
```

the main issue is the mainloop function, possible problems can be created from bootstrapping method.

Comment: I thought I noticed recently that 'Available' was not updating, I seemed to have to read from the client to check for new data.

Comment: so this is an issue with the class and not my code? can you suggest a solution for a switch?

Comment: I can't swear to be be an actual issue, it might be by-design/something that I did not understand, but at least seemed to be the case.  For this particular piece of code, I replaced it with an attempt to read bytes instead and checked to see if the array/'recvBytes.Length' was >/greater-than 0.

Comment: well this doesnt really matter because it seems like the socket just cant receive at all either way and i have 0 idea on why thats the case. i constantly see data on wireshark being sent aswell

Comment: Going to add- seems like closing and reopening the socket works. No idea why. Not gonna post it as an answer because it's an extremely dumb solution

Comment: Nasty things can happen with the 'UdpClient' (/underlying socket); ensure you close it before trying to re-use it.